# I am wondering whether I keep on using Nozbe or change another tool

Tags: web-apps

Now  I have been trying to use Nozbe. This one has many tutorials, though, I find quite a lot of discrepancies between the present interface and contents and the procedure manual  of Nozbe.

I feel very troublesome if I contact help center of Nozbe whenever I have any question.

1. If I keep on using Nozbe
   Alternatively, I am looking for any forum about discussion, mainly usage of Nozbe.
   Do you know any forum?
2. Change another tool
   My concern is that I prefer the tool, no discrepancies between the present interface and contents and the procedure manual of my desired tool.I would not ask the help center often.

My purpose is that I intend to use my personal to-do management. As group GTD, I will use Trello.

Looking forward to having your reply and advice.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! Please note that this site is about *recommending software meeting specific requirements,* not about *solving issues with software* you already have. If you intended to ask for software, please see  [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) for a guide. Otherwise please check the `/help/ontopic` page of other SE sites to see where your question fits. You could start with [SuperUser](//superuser.com/help/on-topic), for example.

Answer (score 1):

Jakub from Nozbe Team here.

Sorry to see you confused with our help page and visuals. We are constantly working on our manual to keep it up to date; Some of videos and screens were made before changes in the interface, however, they still are accurate in describing features and functions. That means you can follow instruction based on the visuals to do it the same way in a current Nozbe version.

If you feel troublesome, you really shouldn't. Our support team is devoted to their work with a true passion. Just send us an email or write fill a form in the Nozbe app and we'll respond in a short time.

Currently, we don't have any official forum for Nozbe users. We have been considering it. Please check out a Nozbe users' subreddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/nozbe

I'm going to pass your voice on to make sure we're on the right track to improve our help page. Thank you!